# Is the following property of analytic functions true?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f $ be an analytic function on $\Bbb {C} $. At any point $z_0$, for every $\epsilon>0$,  does there exist a neighbourhood $B (z_0, \delta) $ such that for every $z\in B (z_0, \delta) $,  we have $\left|\frac {f (z)-f (z_0)}{z-z_0}-f'(z_0)\right|<\epsilon $?

I see the above argument used quite often. And I don't quite see why this is true. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is the *definition* of $f'(z_0)$, resp. a definition of being analytic at $z_0$

Comment: a definition of being holomorphic, you still have to prove analytic $\implies$ holomorphic, even if it is much easier than holomorphic $\implies$ analytic